# How to do Multiple Proccess in One JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to processes three command.

1. check if input empty or not, if empty the proccess stop, if not continue to command 2 and 3.
2. insert input data to database.
3. show and hide between 2 div.

Here what I try

```js
function SubmitFormData() {
    
        if ($.trim($('#url').val()) == '') {
            alert('Input can not be left blank');
            return false;
        }
    
        var url = $("#url").val();
        $.post("shorten.php", {
                url: url
            },
            function(data) {
                $('#result_div').html(data);
                $('#short_form')[0].reset();
            });
    
        $("#result_div").hide();
        $("#submit").show();
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $("#result_div").slideToggle();
            $("#short_div").slideToggle();
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-12" id="short_form" name="short_form" method="post">
        <div class="input-group" id="short_div">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Your Long URL" required>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button type="button" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="SubmitFormData();"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" id="result_div">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your `return false` is outside of the `if` statement and will always be executed.

Comment: What problem are you having? Please describe how the code you have isn't working. You can use the [edit] link under the question to add more information.

Comment: @CindyMeister i dont know where is wrong, cause showing nothing. when i click the button nothing happen.

Comment: @CertainPerformance its work up to proccess 2, but not working whe proccess 3, the `short_div` dont hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A/C to the description given by you :-

You are on right track just try like the code given, it should work for you -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#result_div').hide();
   $('#submit').on('click', function(){
       var inputVal = $.trim($("#url").val());
       if(inputVal != ''){
          $.post('shorten.php', {url: inputVal}, function(response){
              $('#result_div').html(response).show();
              $('#short_form')[0].reset(); 
          });
        $("#result_div").slideToggle();
                $("#short_div").slideToggle();
       }else{
           alert('Please insert valid input')
        }
   });

});
```

Comment: you forget togle betwen show and hide div, im modify it and now working, thanks for u code. acc my edit then ill acc u answer.

Comment: @Jazuly, Thanks for the concern, already written show in post callback function, don't think we need to slideToggle then.

Comment: i try u code given, but toggle not working if im not add it.